# Differentiating a Lagrangian in the Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

I am currently working with an appropriate Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2m}(m\overrightarrow{v}+\frac{q}{c}\overrightarrow{A})^2-(\frac{q^2}{2mC^2})\overrightarrow{A}\cdot \overrightarrow{A}-q\phi$

I am trying to apply the Euler Langrange equation to this Lagrangian.

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL}{dv_x})-\frac{dL}{dx}=0$

So far I have managed to determine the first factor like so

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL}{dv_x})=m\frac{dv_X}{dt}+\frac{q}{c}(v_x\frac{dA_x}{dx}+v_y\frac{dA_x}{dy}+v_z\frac{dA_x}{dz}+\frac{dA_x}{dt})$

and this eventually gives

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL}{dv_x})=\frac{d}{dt}(mv_x+\frac{q}{c}A_x)=m\frac{dv_x}{dt}+\frac{q}{c}\frac{dA_x}{dt}$

$\overrightarrow{A}=A_x\hat{x}+A_y\hat{y}+A_z\hat{z}$

However I am having difficulty attempting the second factor $\frac{dL}{dx}$ could I have some help on how I go about solving this?

Comment: What does $\mathbf A$ and $\phi$ depend on?

Comment: I have added A's dependence and $\phi$ is simply a scalar potential so I think it vanishes in differential due to its constant nature